# Advertising open science in job market with a different norm

Tags: postdocs, faculty-application, interview, presentation, open-science

i am a postdoc at one of the US-based institutions. I have been invited to give a job talk for a faculty position in another country (i will call country A).

Recently, i was browsing the faculty members’ websites in the department in country A. I found that none of their labs practices open science (for example, pre-registering their hypothesis before data collection, uploading their data or materials online), which is kind of becoming a norm in my field in the US.

Originally, before seeing their websites, i was planning to advertise in my job talk that i have pre-registered all my studies and wanted to say that i’d like to design & teach a class about open science.

But now that i have learned that none of the faculty members in the department practices open science, i’m not sure if it’s a good idea to mention these things in my job talk or interview. It’s because it might come across as calling them out like “i’m doing good science, you guys are doing bad science.”

**What do you think? Would it be a good idea to tell the faculty members who do not care about open science that i practice open science and want to teach open science class?**

Comment: I would hope they are seeking to hire a faculty member who brings new things to the department.  Maybe they are, or maybe they prefer to hire someone who is just like themselves.  We wouldn't know.  Present it as a new thing you can bring to the institution.

Comment: You said they don't advertise on their websites that they do open science. I'm not sure you can conclude from that that they actually don't do it.

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear. I looked up their recent pubs, not just their websites.